# "‘CLOCK_PER_SEC’ was not declared in this scope" error even after including <time.h>

Tags: c++

I'm getting "‘CLOCK_PER_SEC’ was not declared in this scope" error even after including time.h.
I'm very newbie to c++, so this will be related to simple mistakes, but i sadly can't figure out. please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>


#define SIZE 1024*1024*1
#define REPEAT 10

using namespace std;

....... 

int main()
{

    const int n = SIZE;


    int* arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {       
        arr[i] = n - i;
    }


    double totalSeiralTime = 0;
    clock_t clock_s, clock_e;
    for(int i = 0; i < REPEAT ; i++)
    {
        clock_s = clock();

        radixsort(arr, n);

        clock_e = clock();
        double cpu_time_used = ((double)(clock_e-clock_s))/CLOCK_PER_SEC; 
        printf("gpu parallel time : %f\n", cpu_time_used);  
        totalSeiralTime += cpu_time_used;
    }
    printf("cpu serial time mean : %f\n", totalSeiralTime / REPEAT);
  return 0;

}
```

how i compile

```
gcc -std=c++11 ./cpuRadix.cpp -o ./cpuRadix.out
./cpuRadix.out
```

I also have tried without std option. But It didn't make change.

Comment: You have typo should be `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` not `CLOCK_PER_SEC`.

Comment: It's `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. With an `S` after `CLOCK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct constant is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Also in c++ the correct header names are:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

(most implementations this doesn't matter but it's what the standard says you have to include)

Comment: `<time.h>` works just fine in standard C++.

Comment: Voting to close for typo is the right response to the question, not posting an answer.